# Sum of roots of trigonometric equation

Tags: functions, trigonometry, parametric

This is the hardest problem on Georgian (country) high school math exam.

Find all values for parameter $a$ for which the sum of all the roots of the equation:

$$\sin\left(\sqrt {ax-x^2}\right)=0 $$

equal to $100$.

Note that you can't use calculus and we assume only real roots!

Comment: Presumably all the **real** roots.

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: Is this an exam being given now, or is it an old one?

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck? This helps in getting more useful answers.

Comment: This one is from 2014 and majority of people think that this is the hardest question in the history of Georgian exams.

Comment: Has Vieta's formula been taught in high school?

Comment: @Trebor To be honest I couldn't do anything productive. Only trivial part in my opinion which is ax-x^2=pi*k where k is an integer and sum of roots in each this type of equations is equals to a.

Comment: @DuFong Yes it's taught. See my latest comment please

Comment: @NikaChelidze Shouldn't it be $ax-x^2=\pi^2 k^2$?

Comment: @Divide1918 Yes it's typo sorry i'll edit

Comment: Is this the same question you asked a month ago? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3678113/trigonometry-parametric-equation-sin-sqrt-ax-x2-0?rq=1

Comment: @DuFong Yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $a>0$, and the equation reads

$$ax-x^2=k^2\pi^2.$$

By Vieta, when you add the roots in pairs, the sum is $a$.

Hence with $k\ge0$

$$(k+1)a=100$$ with $$a\ge 2k\pi$$

or

$$(k+1)a=100\ge 4(k+1)k\pi.$$

Finally,

$$a=\frac{100}{k+1}$$ with $k=0,1,2.$

Note that as $a$ is rational and $\pi$ transcendental, there is no risk of equal roots.

Comment: Can you explain what (k+1) is? Is this number or equations?

Comment: @NikaChelidze: the number of pairs of roots for a given $a$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I plugged in your answer with k=0 (and so a=50), and I got $0\le k\le 7$, which means there are 8 possible values for k. Hence the sum of roots in this case is 400 instead of 100. Unless I've made some error...

Comment: Are you sure it's 2(k+1) and not 2k+1?

Comment: I this helps you answer is a=25

Comment: @Divide1918 To be honest I absolutely didn't get where 2(k+1) or 2k+1 comes from

Comment: @NikaChelidze $2k+1$ comes from all complex roots. since square $\pm k$  equals $k$ and $0$ only be counted once.

Comment: @Divide1918: why would it be $2k+1$ ?

Comment: @Divide1918 I think the comment above yours is correct about this.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Can you explain $2(k+1)a=100≥4(k+1)kπ$ how did you get this?

Comment: @NikaChelidze: complex root ? What complex roots ? And $k=0$ also yields two roots, obviously.

Comment: @YvesDaoust k equals 0, you do have two roots, but it is their sum equals a, not 2a.

Comment: @DuFong: quite right, and this is true for any $k$. That makes my whole answer wrong. Fixing.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: what is the sum of the roots of $\sqrt{a x - x^2} = n \pi$?

Comment: I know that's a but i can't continue exactly from here

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the real zeros of $ax-x^2=k\pi$ are $x_{k1}$ and $x_{k2}$, then from the condition we have
$$\sum_{\text{all possible $k$}}(x_{k1}+x_{k2})=100.$$

Now since the zeros are real, we also need $a^2-4k^2\pi^2\geq 0$ which gives us an upper bound of the possible $k$:$\frac{a}{2\pi}$, while it is also evident to see the lower bound should be $\frac{a}{2\pi}-1$, then apply Vieta's formula,(note 0 only be counted once, so there are $N+1$ $a$'s.) And we have
$$\frac{100}{\frac{a}{2\pi}+1}\leq a\leq \frac{100}{\frac{a}{2\pi}}.$$
A rough estimate gives that $22.12\leq a\leq 25.06$, however since $N$ is an integer, and $a=\frac{100}{N+1}$, so $a=25$.

**Note**:If $a=25$, then we have $k=0, 1, 2, 3$ and sum all up gives $25*4$ which is 100.

Comment: Sorry for this many questions but to be absolutely clear I want to know 100/(a/2π+1)≤a≤100/(a/2π) comes from?

Comment: @NikaChelidze since $(N+1)a=100$, and $N\leq a/{2\pi}-1$, thus $a=100/(N+1)\leq 100/(a/2\pi-1+1)$, other half is similar.